# Set Minimum date for X Axis in scatter plot ChartJS

Tags: javascript, react-chartjs, chartjs-2.6.0

When I pass my data points with a numerical value for the Y coordinate and a date value for the x coordinate the scatter plot starts the x axis at 1976 even though my earliest date is 2018.
How can I set the x axis starting value? 
Here is what my data and options look like.
Date Format: 2018/06/30

```
data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Scatter Dataset',
        data: [{
            x: 10,
            y: ‘2018/06/30’
        }, {
            x: 0,
            y: ‘2018/06/01’
        }, {
            x: 100,
            y: ‘2018/06/04’
        }]
    }]
}
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
                     ticks: {
                     suggestedMin: ‘2018/01/01’,
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I have trying passing new Date(‘2018/01/01’) to the suggestedMin, I have also tried using Min instead of suggestedMin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can add minimum starting point on x axis like this,

```
data: {
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Scatter Dataset',
            data: [
                {
                    x: 10,
                    y: ‘2018/06/30’
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: ‘2018/06/01’
                }, {
                    x: 100,
                    y: ‘2018/06/04’
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: '2018/01/01',
            },
            time: {
                min:2018/01/01,
                max:2028/02/02
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: For me just the `time: {min: '2020-06-29', max: '2020-07-31'}` part worked. `suggestedMin` did not work on its own (was less than data minimum).

Comment: ya maybe suggestedMin meant for ticks only

Comment: This saved a lot of time from me :)